# Reference parameters (&$a) in functions, good or bad?

Tags: php, function, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

We've coded two validation functions, one is like below (it gets all the fields at once):

```
function check_fields(&$arr,&$msg,$types,$lens,$captions,$requireds) {}
```

and the other function is something like below:

```
function is_valid($field=NULL,$type=0 ,$length=0,$required=true) {}
```

First function has a few code lines, and reduces code lines dramatically (about 30-35 lines or even more), on the other side the second function without reference increases the code lines (about 30-35 lines or even more).

We have to call the second function for every field we want to validate, but the first function (`check_fields`) is vice versa.
I've read in an article long time ago that functions with reference parameters are bad from a performance point of view.

Now we don't know which function to use. Which one is better from a performance perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think I got my answer myself after some web searches:

[Do not use PHP references](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/125-Do-not-use-PHP-references.html)

Comment: whatever works for you. If you want to follow proper OO then create class and pass instance of that class instead of half dozen parameters. Objects are passed by ref in php5 so you can alter it as needed. Use typecasting to ensure proper class is passed. In my opinion you are concentrating on the wrong things.... if you want to optimize your code concentrate on database calls and disk r/w.

Answer (score 1):

use the solution that is simpler to use and easier to maintain. 
You are talking about micro optimization, which is pretty much useless.

---

use references because in your case it is simpler solution and requires less code.

Comment: Specially when he gets the code to a less-readable level just to achieve micro optimization!

Comment: This is not my answer, I actually want to know which one is better and why, please don't say something like this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just remember this, when you called:

```
   <?php 
    $a = 1 ;
    echo "As initial, the real 'a' is..".$a."<br/>";
    $b = &$a ; // it's meaning $b has the same value as $a, $b = $a AND SO $a = $b (must be)
    $b += 5;
    echo "b is equal to: ".$b." and a equal to: ".$a."<br/>";
    echo " Now we back as initial, when a=1... (see the source code) <br/>";
    $a = 1 ;
    echo "After we back : b is equal to: ".$b." and a equal to: ".$a."<br/>";
    echo "Wait, why b must follow a? ... <br/> ..what about if we change b alone? (see the source code)<br/>";
    $b = 23; 
    echo "After we change b alone, b equal to: ".$b." and a equal to: ".$a."<br/>";
    echo " WHAT ?? a ALSO CHANGED ?? a and b STICK TOGETHER?!! </br>" ;
    echo "to 'clear this, we use 'unset' function on a (see the source code)<br/> ";
    unset($a);
    $b = 66;
    $a = 1;
    echo "Now, after unset,b is equal to: ".$b." and a equal to: ".$a."<br/>"; 
    ?>
```

And the Output will be:

```
As initial, the real 'a' is..1
After the Reference operator...(see the source code)
b is equal to: 11 and a equal to: 11
Now we back as initial... (see the source code) 
After we back : b is equal to: 1 and a equal to: 1
Wait, why b must follow a? ... 
..what about if we change b alone? (see the source code)
After we change b alone, b equal to: 23 and a equal to: 23
WHAT ?? a ALSO CHANGED ?? a and b STICK TOGETHER?!! 
to 'clear this, we use 'unset' function on a (see the source code)
Now, after unset,b is equal to: 66 and a equal to: 1
```

Review:

Why did `$a` change? That's because `&` (the ampersand operator) made `&` as a reference variable, hence it stored in a 'temporary memory'. When you intitialized `$b= &$a`, see my comment `$b = $a` *and also* `$a = $b`, that means whenever you modified `$b`, `$a` was also modified, and vice versa. *They are chained*! That's the simple meaning of the reference operator.

Maybe at the beginning it feels confusing, but once you become an expert with this, you can handle this operator to make a "switching" function like this:

```
<?php

function bulbswitch(&$switch)
{
    $switch = !$switch;    

}

function lightbulb($a)
{
    if ($a == true) { echo 'a is On <br/>';}
    else { echo 'a is Off <br/>';}
}

$a = true ;
echo 'At the begining, a is On, then.... <br/>';

bulbswitch($a);
lightbulb($a);
bulbswitch($a);
lightbulb($a);
bulbswitch($a);
lightbulb($a);
bulbswitch($a);
lightbulb($a);
bulbswitch($a);
lightbulb($a);
bulbswitch($a);
lightbulb($a);
?>
```

The output will be:

```
At the begining, a is On, then.... 
a is Off 
a is On 
a is Off 
a is On 
a is Off 
a is On
```

Comment: I tried to edit this, but your edit overrode mine... you must *not* indent normal text, or everything will show up as code.

Comment: Thanks, but now I am fixed it.. See?

Comment: Well, everything is still in the code block, so no ;)

Comment: please [edit] this answer and remove the extra indents. See also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help